# Initializing std::vector outside of main() causes performance drop (multithreading)

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, vector

I'm writing a path tracer as a programming exercise. Yesterday I finally decided to implement multithreading - and it worked well. However, once I wrapped the test code I wrote inside `main()` in a separate `renderer` class, I noticed a significant and consistent performance drop. In short - it would seem that filling `std::vector` anywhere outside of `main()` causes threads using its elements to perform worse. I managed to isolate and reproduce the issue with simplified code, but unfortunately I still don't know why it happens or what to do in order to fix it.

Performance drop is quite visible and consistent:

```
  97 samples - time = 28.154226s, per sample = 0.290250s, per sample/th = 1.741498
  99 samples - time = 28.360723s, per sample = 0.286472s, per sample/th = 1.718832
 100 samples - time = 29.335468s, per sample = 0.293355s, per sample/th = 1.760128

vs.

  98 samples - time = 30.197734s, per sample = 0.308140s, per sample/th = 1.848841
  99 samples - time = 30.534240s, per sample = 0.308427s, per sample/th = 1.850560
 100 samples - time = 30.786519s, per sample = 0.307865s, per sample/th = 1.847191
```

The code I originally posted in this question can be found here: https://github.com/Jacajack/rt/tree/mt_debug or in edit history.

I created a struct `foo` that is supposed to mimic the behavior of my `renderer` class and is responsible for initialization of path tracing contexts in its constructor.
The interesting thing is, when I remove the body of `foo`'s constructor and instead do this (initialize `contexts` directly from `main()`):

```cpp
std::vector<rt::path_tracer> contexts; // Can be on stack or on heap, doesn't matter
foo F(cam, scene, bvh, width, height, render_threads, contexts); // no longer fills `contexts`

contexts.reserve(render_threads);
for (int i = 0; i < render_threads; i++)
    contexts.emplace_back(cam, scene, bvh, width, height, 1000 + i);

F.run(render_threads);
```

the performance is back to normal. But then, if I wrap these three lines into a separate function and call it from here, it's worse again. The only pattern I can see here is
that filling the `contexts` vector outside of `main()` causes the problem.

I initially thought that this was an alignment/caching issue, so I tried aligning `path_tracer`s with Boost's `aligned_allocator` and TBB's `cache_aligned_allocator` with no result. It turns out that this problem persists even when there's only *one thread running.*
I suspect it must be some kind of wild compiler optimization (I'm using `-O3`), althought that's just a guess. Do you know any possible causes of such behavior and what can be done to avoid it?

This happens on both `gcc` 10.1.0 and `clang` 10.0.0. Currently I'm only using `-O3`.

I managed to reproduce a similar issue in this standalone example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

struct foo
{
    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist;
    std::vector<float> buf;
    int cnt = 0;
    
    foo(int seed, int n) :
        rng(seed),
        dist(0, 1),
        buf(n, 0)
    {
    }
    
    void do_stuff()
    {
        // Do whatever
        for (auto &f : buf)
            f = (f + 1) * dist(rng);
        cnt++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int N = 50000000;
    int thread_count = 6;
    
    struct bar
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        std::vector<foo> &foos;
        bool active = true;
        
        bar(std::vector<foo> &f, int thread_count, int n) :
            foos(f)
        {
            /*
            foos.reserve(thread_count);
            for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
                foos.emplace_back(1000 + i, n);
            //*/
        }
        
        void run(int thread_count)
        {
            auto task = [this](foo &f)
            {
                while (this->active)
                    f.do_stuff();
            };

            threads.reserve(thread_count);
            for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
                threads.emplace_back(task, std::ref(foos[i]));
        }
    };
    
    
    std::vector<foo> foos;
    bar B(foos, thread_count, N);
    
    ///*
    foos.reserve(thread_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
        foos.emplace_back(1000 + i, N);
    //*/
    
    B.run(thread_count);
    
    std::vector<float> buffer(N, 0);
    int samples = 0, last_samples = 0;
    
    // Start time
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    while (1)
    {
        last_samples = samples;
        samples = 0;
        for (auto &f : foos)
        {
            std::transform(
                f.buf.cbegin(), f.buf.cend(),
                buffer.begin(),
                buffer.begin(),
                std::plus<float>()
            );
            samples += f.cnt;
        }
        
        if (samples != last_samples)
        {
            auto t_now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::chrono::duration<double> t_total = t_now - t_start;
            std::cerr << std::setw(4) << samples << " samples - time = " << std::setw(8) << std::fixed << t_total.count() 
                << "s, per sample = " << std::setw(8) << std::fixed << t_total.count() / samples 
                << "s, per sample/th = " << std::setw(8) << std::fixed << t_total.count() / samples * thread_count << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

and results:

```
For N = 100000000, thread_count = 6

In main():
 196 samples - time = 26.789526s, per sample = 0.136681s, per sample/th = 0.820088
 197 samples - time = 27.045646s, per sample = 0.137288s, per sample/th = 0.823725
 200 samples - time = 27.312159s, per sample = 0.136561s, per sample/th = 0.819365


vs.
In foo::foo():
 193 samples - time = 22.690566s, per sample = 0.117568s, per sample/th = 0.705406
 196 samples - time = 22.972403s, per sample = 0.117206s, per sample/th = 0.703237
 198 samples - time = 23.257542s, per sample = 0.117462s, per sample/th = 0.704774
 200 samples - time = 23.540432s, per sample = 0.117702s, per sample/th = 0.706213
```

It seems that the results are the opposite of what is happening in my path tracer, but the visible difference is still here.

Thank you

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Have you enabled compiler optimizations? If not, do that as step 1.

Comment: Please provide [mre]s, details do matter. Also include all compiler flags you used to compile

Comment: Initially I've had `-ffast-math`, `-march=native`, `-ftree-vectorize` and `-O3` enabled. Now I only have `-O3` and it still happens.

Comment: You should also include the benchmark (details do matter)

Comment: Alright, I will try to reproduce the issue in a separate program. Meanwhile the original faulty code can be found here: https://github.com/Jacajack/rt/tree/mt_debug The benchmark I'm currently using simply checks `sample_count` of each `path_tracer` and if the sum of samples changes, it prints time divided by the total number of samples.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've added a standalone example, which exhibits similar behavior. Should I remove the original code from my question then?

Comment: Yes, go for it. There is no answer yet that would reference the old code, and if someone wants to see the old code it's not permanently removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a race condition with `foo::buf` - one thread makes stores into it, anther reads it. This is undefined behaviour, but on x86-64 platform that is harmless in this particular code.

---

I cannot reproduce your observations on Intel i9-9900KS, both variants print the same `per sample` stats.

Compiled with gcc-8.4, `g++ -o release/gcc/test.o -c -pthread -m{arch,tune}=native -std=gnu++17 -g -O3 -ffast-math -falign-{functions,loops}=64 -DNDEBUG test.cc`

With `int N = 50000000;` each thread operates on its own array of `float[N]` which occupies 200MB. Such a data set doesn't fit in CPU caches and the program incurs a lot of data cache misses because it needs to fetch the data from memory:

```
$ perf stat -ddd ./release/gcc/test
[...]
      71474.813087      task-clock (msec)         #    6.860 CPUs utilized          
                66      context-switches          #    0.001 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           341,942      page-faults               #    0.005 M/sec                  
   357,027,759,875      cycles                    #    4.995 GHz                      (30.76%)
   991,950,515,582      instructions              #    2.78  insn per cycle           (38.43%)
   105,609,126,987      branches                  # 1477.571 M/sec                    (38.40%)
       155,426,137      branch-misses             #    0.15% of all branches          (38.39%)
   150,832,846,580      L1-dcache-loads           # 2110.294 M/sec                    (38.41%)
     4,945,287,289      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    3.28% of all L1-dcache hits    (38.44%)
     1,787,635,257      LLC-loads                 #   25.011 M/sec                    (30.79%)
     1,103,347,596      LLC-load-misses           #   61.72% of all LL-cache hits     (30.81%)
   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads                                             
         7,457,756      L1-icache-load-misses                                         (30.80%)
   150,527,469,899      dTLB-loads                # 2106.021 M/sec                    (30.80%)
        54,966,843      dTLB-load-misses          #    0.04% of all dTLB cache hits   (30.80%)
            26,956      iTLB-loads                #    0.377 K/sec                    (30.80%)
           415,128      iTLB-load-misses          # 1540.02% of all iTLB cache hits   (30.79%)
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetches                                        
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                                   

      10.419122076 seconds time elapsed
```

If you run this application on NUMA CPUs, such as AMD Ryzen and Intel Xeon with multiple sockets, then your observations can probably be explained by adverse placement of threads onto remote NUMA nodes relative to NUMA node where `foo::buf` is allocated. Those last-level data cache misses have to read memory and if that memory is in a remote NUMA node that takes longer.

To fix that, you may like to allocate memory in the thread that uses it (not in the main thread as the code does) and use a NUMA-aware allocator, such as [TCMalloc](https://github.com/google/tcmalloc). See [NUMA aware heap memory manager](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/NUMA_aware_heap_memory_manager_article_final.pdf) for more details.

---

When running your benchmark you may like to fix the CPU frequency, so that it doesn't get dynamically adjusted during the run, on Linux you can do that with `sudo cpupower frequency-set --related --governor performance`.

Comment: I'm aware of that race condition, but I accepted it for the sake of having a live preview. My CPU is i7-8700k and the differences are clear for any number of threads (including 1 and with fixed frequency too). I'll try running this code on other computers to see how it behaves and will report my results. Allocating memory per thread seems to be a reasonable approach too - I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacajack On non-NUMA CPU, like i7-8700k, you don't need NUMA-aware memory allocation.

Comment: Yes, but at least that's something new to try, in case I don't find out what's wrong. Here are my results for Core 2 Duos - the differences are smaller, but are visible: https://pastebin.com/XuZFW3iv After seeing your compilation command, I tried adding `-falign-*=64` my path tracer's CMake - unfortunately with no result.

Comment: @Jacajack I just verified my code, executables and results and also ran the benchmark on Intel Xeon Gold 6132. I do not observe any difference. I suspect you compile and run code different from the one you posted.

Comment: I just checked what I posted against what I'm compiling with diff and there are no differences. Anyway, I've implemented `path_tracer` allocation per thread in my path tracer and started using floating point sample number values (updated with each pixel) and the results are much less noisy. I let it run and left my computer for a longer while and it converged to "right" time values. Can't really say whether that's thanks to better probing or changing allocation scheme. I will implement per thread statistics and see if those look right.

Comment: Also, I'll let the test code run for a *longer* while in each configuration and see if they eventually converge to the same value. Maybe it's just a matter of different convergence rate? (which would be quite weird anyway...)

Comment: I made this plot: https://imgur.com/a/Ps6IceR and it seems that they all eventually converge to *roughly* the same value after a longer period of time. At the beginning, the differences are obviously larger (and apparently "init in main" version happens to be faster here? At least from looking at the chart...) and that's what made me think that there was a big overall difference. I guess I'll just have to be more patient when benchmarking in the future. Thanks for your time!